# Unable to use .find() to get value from table/form

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to wrap my head around this for a while now. Some guru needs to help me out, it would be greatly appreciated. I don't know why it is not working.

```js
$(".form").on('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); //prevent the forms default action
  var surname = $(this).find(".surname");
  console.log(surname);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <form class="form" method="post" action="nextpage.php">
    <tr>
      <td class="name">john</td>
      <td class="surname">smith</td>
      <td>british</td>
      <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Submit</button></td>
    </tr>

  </form>

  <form class="form" method="post" action="nextpage.php">
    <tr>
      <td class="name">bob</td>
      <td class="surname">doe</td>
      <td>american</td>
      <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Submit</button></td>
    </tr>
  </form>
</table>
```

So if i click on the first submit button i should see john, and the second, bob.

Comment: A `<form>` is not a valid descendant of a `<table>`

Comment: And a form without anything to submit doesn't make much sense either.

Comment: It should be var surname = $(this).find(".surname").text(); What do you get in console log?

Comment: Sorry, i do have .text() coded.

Comment: @CertainPerformance - is it not? How would i make this approach valid then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed your code:

1. The `<form>` wraps *around* the `<table>`
2. Catch the clicks on `<buttons>` and get the surname relatively to the clicked row (`<tr>`)

```js
$("button[type=submit]").on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); //prevent the forms default action
  var surname = $(this).closest('tr').find(".surname");
  console.log(surname.text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form" method="post" action="nextpage.php">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">john</td>
      <td class="surname">smith</td>
      <td>british</td>
      <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Submit</button></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="name">bob</td>
      <td class="surname">doe</td>
      <td>american</td>
      <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Submit</button></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v9k3sL1f/

Answer (score 2):

As statet in the comments your HTML semantics is wrong. That's the first reason why it doesn't work. The second thing is you might want to use jQuerys [.text()](https://api.jquery.com/text/) to get the "value" of a HTML element.

To make it work, see the example `<table>` element is now moved inside the `<form>` element. Depending on your needs this is one possible solution.

```js
$(".form").on('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); //prevent the forms default action
  var surname = $(this).find(".surname");
  console.log(surname.text()); // here .text() is the only change in your js code
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <form class="form" method="post" action="nextpage.php">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">john</td>
      <td class="surname">smith</td>
      <td>british</td>
      <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Submit</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
  </form>

  <form class="form" method="post" action="nextpage.php">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">bob</td>
      <td class="surname">doe</td>
      <td>american</td>
      <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Submit</button></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
```

Read more about permitted elements inside the `<table>` element here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table

Read more about permitted elements inside `<form>` tag here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form

Comment: Hi. Sorry i forgot to include the .text() in my example. Why would the table need to go inside the form? Above comments say my example is not a valid descendant. Can you explain that... Thanks a bunch

Comment: @Leo505 follow the link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table and read "Permitted content" bullet list. Those are the only allowed elements (direct descendants) from the `<table>` element.

Answer (score 0):

just put the class="form" and action inside the tr tag and it'll works.